# How do I post data to rails app from iOS

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, frontend

I have a scaffolded app that supports JSON of sending data. But I also want to be able to post data from my iOS client. In my rails view i think the data is updated through patch, but does it support handling a JSON sent from the client? I.e. I want to use the rails backend for an iOS app. Could i use NSURL or am I better of using ASIHttpRequest or something similar?

This is what is sent from the rails-view, and what i want to replicate in the iOS client:

```
Started PATCH "/games/3" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-13 15:14:29 +0200
Processing by GamesController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", 
"authenticity_token"=>"kuvkDtGT7M5ym1xYbe4NJlX+vIhG2n4IlxoA+7XAdZw=", 
"game"=>{"name"=>"", 
"levels_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"score"=>"10", "id"=>"120"}, 
"1"=>{"score"=>"30", "id"=>"121"}}}, 
"commit"=>"Store Result", "id"=>"3"}
```

I Also need to handle the authentication, I guess i could store the token in a local object (after login in through a webview) and pass it in every request. The image below shows a webview in the app with the login:

[image]